# How to selectivly compile C# projects in Visual Studio 2005?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2005

I have the following setup:

- Project A
- Project B depends on A

Each project has pre and post build events. Most of the time I make changes in project B. So every time I tell VS to only compile project B the other project is compiled too. This happens despite the facts that no changes where done to A and a up to date DLL for A is present.

How do I tell VS to only compile project B in this case?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you right click on the solution and select configuration manager you can tell the projects not to build.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't very healthy, do make sure that Build + Rebuild works to verify that no circular dependency snuck in.  Next step is to get more diagnostic info out of msbuild to see why it thinks it needs to build A.  Tools + Options, Projects and Solutions, Build and Run.  Change the MSBuild project build output verbosity setting to "Diagnostic".

Answer (score 0):

You can use Shift-F6 to build an individual project.